# run a scheduled task in Windows XP without log in

Tags: vbscript, windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

I have been developing a program that needs to be run daily bases. I set this as a scheduled task and put a specific time to run. But it only runs when I log on. Although I unchecked the "Run only if logged on" option, it doesn't run until I log on. My question is, is there any way to run a scheduled task without logging on?

Edit: the program that has to be run daily doesn't have a GUI, it's a visual basic script needs to be run on background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need a service for that, too much to handle in this space, google "windows run program as a service"